# Copying complex data structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, decorator, composite

I am using Composite pattern in my Java program, such that a Component is being extended by three classes.

1. Leaf class extends Component
2. Composite extends Component
3. Decorator extends Component (for decorating leafs)

The composite is currently implemented using a List, where each element can either be a leaf, another Composite or a decorator. I am thinking of adding undo/redo functionality for which I am going to be using Command/Memento patterns.

Now my question, how can I create a deep copy of my list here, so that I can restore it later? Basically, need to find a way that allows me to create a new identical copy of my list at the current time before executing another command. I am thinking there has to be some recursive way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest approach to code (but perhaps not the cheapest in terms of the overall CPU and memory use) is to mark your classes serializable, serialize the list into a memory buffer, and then deserialize it back into an object. If you do it right, the result is going to be a deep copy of your list of objects.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Actually, my data structure is pretty small, so cpu/memory use is not a serious concern here. Thanks @dasblinkenlight